# Changing font color in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to change the size and color of my font on a wordpress menu,however when i use the following code

```
#access ul{
 font-size:25px;
 color:red;
}
```

the size changes but color remains the same, how can i edit my code to get the color working as well

Comment: looks like it's overridden by other style, try this `color:red!important;` but it's just used to test.

Comment: Post the HTML for your menu.

Comment: We need to see the HTML, and probably the CSS you're trying to override. To find out directly what to override, use your browser's debugging tools to find the style that's applying the current colour, then target that. (My guess: as it's a menu, the text is contained in an anchor element, i.e. it's a link, which will often be specifically styled. Wild stab in the dark: `#access ul li a { color: red; }`.)

Comment: I highly recommend using "Fire Bug" in FireFox.  When you install this add on, you can right click on an anything on your page and select "Inspect Element".  It will then show you the code and what css elements are affecting it.  You'll be able to see what line in which css file too which is very handy.  Chrome also has this but I think it is built into the browser without adding it as an add-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change non-current menu items with...

```
#access li a { color: #000; }
```

and if the current page is the current menu item change the built-in wordpress class...

```
.current-menu-item a { color:#FFF; }
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Something is overriding on the properties you set here in CSS.
(2) Change the color of li instead of ul
(3) Provide your ul structure code also

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#access ul{font-size:25px; color:red !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the color property is inherited, but anchor elements does not inherit attributes like color. If you want your `<a>` tags to inherit the color use:

```
#access a { color: inherit; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#access li a { 
 color: red; 
}
```

or

```
a{
 color:inherit
}

#access li{
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: This answer sees similar to two of the answers already given.